# Prevent page back button , Ionic2 on specific conditions

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic2.
I have few pages and flow - P1 -> P2 -> P3.

I want to use `ionViewCanLeave()` on P3, so that if certain conditions are not met, it should give alert when user presses back button.

```
this.navCtrl.pop()
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('should I stay or should I go now');
  });

ionViewCanLeave(): boolean{
   // here we can either return true or false
   // depending on if we want to leave this view
   let percentMarks = Math.floor((this.totalCorrectAnswers / this.questionSetChosen.length) * 100);
   if(percentMarks > 0){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

But it is giving an error.

Comment: what error does it give?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong... this function `ionViewCanLeave` runs on leave so at that moment you should check if is possible. Hope this can help you.

```
ionViewCanLeave() {
  let percentMarks = Math.floor((this.totalCorrectAnswers /
                     this.questionSetChosen.length) * 100);

  if(percentMarks > 0){
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  } else {
    console.log('i should stay'));
  }
```